# SPS2SAppResourcePolicyException on SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, rest, social

I have a SharePoint 2013 Provider Hosted App (on premise).  When I try to make a social rest call I get the following error code:

> -2146232832, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.SPS2SAppResourcePolicyException

with the following error message:

> An app requested information that is not available from this location

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.sps2sappresourcepolicyexception.aspx) doesn't provide any clarification on this

Answer (score 1):

I think I'm 100% wrong, but let me give you something to go on with. 
[Do you think maybe you need to ask permission to use the User Profiles?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hrN9.png)

It doesn't make sense to me why you'd need the user's permission for it, but it's better than the no responses you're getting now, right? Hopefully it's a starting point.

Comment: Yeah - I read up on permissions and you need Read permissions on User Profiles and write permissions at the Tenant level.

Comment: So were you able to get it to work using that method? If so, this would be a great Community topic to keep here. I haven't done much Windows 8 development but from all the seminars and workshops I've seen getting system permission is done the way I show in the screenshot I attached.That's why my first thought was that SharePoint probably does it the same way.

Comment: Sorry - I meant to say that those are the permissions I have set according to the documentation.  Unfortunately those permissions still don't allow access.

Comment: Could you modify your question to include the REST call as well as your AppManifest.xml?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this same issue recently and it took me a while to figure out that my distributed cache service instance was corrupted.

If you have the same problem as I had then you should be able to access

`~webAppUrl/_api/social.feed/my/`

**but not**

`~webAppUrl/_api/social.feed/my/feed` or `~webAppUrl/_api/social.feed/my/news`

Make sure your DC configuration is correct and then run the two lines below with admin rights. Note: I could not manually start the DC service.

```
Remove-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
Add-SPDistributedCacheServiceInstance
```

As soon as the DC was working properly I was able to access the two feed URLs above.